# How can I use multple textbox with different names in array to to insert multiple rows in mysql

Tags: php

I have HTML textboxes with different names, like fullname, schoolcode, score. These text boxes were generated from a query against my table. From the result returned, I would like to insert their values in multiple rows.

The below code is what I have tried so far

```
/* below code display the form input tags in this form */
$sql = $xconnect->prepare("select * from table group by(schoolcode)");
$sql->execute();
$count = $sql->rowCount();
if ($count == 0) {
    echo "No result found";
} else {
    echo '<form method="POST" action="">';
    while ($row = $sql->fetch()) {
        echo '<input type="text" value="'.$row["fullname"].
        '" name="fullname[]">'.
        '<input type="hidden" value="'.$row["schoolcode"].
        '" name="schoolcode[]">'.
        '<input type="text" value="" name="score[]">'.
        "<br><br>";
    }
    echo ' <input type="submit" name="submit"> </form>';
}

//and this other code below is to insert the values to multiple rows in Mysql

if (isset($_POST["submit"])) {
    $fullname = "";
    $schoolcode = "";
    $score = "";
    if (!empty($_POST['score'])) {
        $fullname = $_POST['fullname'];
        $schoolcode = $_POST['schoolcode'];
        $score = $_POST['score'];
        for ($i = 0; $i < sizeof($fullname); $i++) {
            $sql2 = $xconnect->prepare("insert into table(fname, scode, score) values (:f, :c, :s)");
            $sql2->execute(array(":f" => $fullname[$i], ":c" => $schoolcode[$i], ":s" => $score[$i], ));
            echo "success";
        }
    }
}
```

The expected result is to display in the format below according to the input score that corresponds with the student's fullname and schoolcode
e.g

```
fullname | schoolcode | score  
---------|------------|------- 
Ken      | 743627373  | 60     
---------|------------|------- 
Jude     | 876735836  | 40     
---------|------------|------- 
Anne     | 657556864  | 70     
---------|------------|------- 
Mike     | 685675112  | 30     
---------|------------|-------
```

Comment: What is your issue here??

Answer (score 0):

May be this will help you

```
if (isset($_POST["submit"])) {
$fullname = "";
$schoolcode = "";
$score = "";
if (!empty($_POST['score'])) {
    $fullname = $_POST['fullname'];
    $schoolcode = $_POST['schoolcode'];
    $score = $_POST['score'];
    echo "<table border='1'>";
    for ($i = 0; $i < sizeof($fullname); $i++) {
        $sql2 = $xconnect->prepare("insert into table(fname, scode, score) values (:f, :c, :s)");
        $sql2->execute(array(":f" => $fullname[$i], ":c" => $schoolcode[$i], ":s" => $score[$i], ));
        echo "<tr><td>".$fullname[$i]."</td><td>".$schoolcode[$i]."</td><td>".$score[$i]."</td></tr>";
    }
    echo "</table>";
}
}
```